# Measuring Temperature of Water-filled Methacrylate Capsule: Laser Thermometer Accuracy and Penetration Depth Inquiry

Tags: water, material-science, laser, measurements

Imagine that I have a methacrylate capsule filled with water (8cm in diameter and 30cm in length). If I wanted to measure the temperature with a laser thermometer pointing at the capsule, what temperature would it be giving me? Would it simply measure the surface temperature, would it penetrate the medium giving me the interior temperature or would it pass through the capsule? Also, how accurate would the measurement be?

Comment: Infrared thermometers have to be corrected for emissivity. The best way to do this is by calibrating the measurement with emitters of known temperature. Install a couple of real thermometers in a test capsule (one on the inside, one outside) and take a bunch of measurements at different temperatures.